# kitchen sink drain replacement

Tags: plumbing

I bought all the metal drain pipes to replace a rotted out existing system under kitchen sink . I showed the plumbing supply vendor a picture and shared my knowledge of the set up . He sold me basically exact matching parts ( metal) / I am very handy at most everything except of course plumbing . The pipes he sold me do match up to my existing rotted pieces except of course some shortening i will need to do with hacksaw.  Big dilemma is how do you fit 1 1/2 inch pipe into 1 1/2 inch pipe . the same diameter cannot fit into another pipe of the same diameter

Comment: Many store bought drain pipes segments are slightly enlarged on one end so the other pipe slips inside it. If you are to couple two generic lengths of drain pipe, then you need a double female coupling for both ends to slip inside.

Comment: thank you so much for that info . I am an electrical engineer and anticipate designs to be appropriate for the job purchased the parts. I did try many failed attempts to make them fit such as heating one side to soften , then cooling to potentially contract one side . Also used the cut and bend method , All failed if course . i did see after more examination that the installer did some jury rigging which of course  made my life more difficult

Comment: There are videos online showing how to do this. Google kitchen sink drain replacement. Here is one that covers the material and shows the parts without assuming a lot of prior knowledge: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HiN4gtzVBtA

Comment: After you understand the parts you are to use, you must learn how to measure to cut the parts to length.

Comment: Opposite extreme video, a pro using a lot of special tools, gluing the PVC drains together https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_aU6wTQT8M

Comment: that video was great .  I didn't know there were special tools to expand the interior diameter of the pipes by auguring them. Very cool !   Understand now that there is no magic solution . I abandoned the metallic pipes I was working with and replaced with pvc extendable pipes etc  trap  joint was exterior to the wall and made it easier to put the puzzle together.  Now i need to connect  dishwasher with to the drain pies a hose. Sink up and running because i plugged up the short input for the dishwasher , You guys are awesome  thanks

Comment: The auger would not be used by a DIYer. It must have been extremely thick wall tubing to allow being augered out. If you don't have a disposer, there is a special fitting for connection of the dishwasher. I think it is usually a special additional tailpiece (the vertical run from the bottom of the sink). Google dishwasher tailpiece.

Comment: In my house built 1970 the drains in the walls and under the slab are ABS plastic. The ABS horizontal drain  going into the wall under the sink is sized so that the PVC drain pipes connected to it have a glued transition piece 135 deg angle and from there it is all 1 1/2 inch plastic with large nut/soft seals. I removed the disposer >30 years ago, and used a tailpiece Wye connection for the dishwasher. We did away with the dishwasher 15 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would have used plastic pipes and fittings as they're much easier to install.

However, as long as you have the metal pieces, you can join them with a "Fernco" rubber joint. It is basically a short rubber hose with hose clamps.